# qt - polyhedron viewer showing nothing

Tags: c++, qt, computational-geometry, cgal

I'm a newbie in using cgal , I tried the following example :

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/draw_polyhedron.h>
#include <fstream>


typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>                       Polyhedron;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Polyhedron P;
    std::ifstream in1((argc>1)?argv[1]:"data/bones.off");
    in1 >> P;
    CGAL::draw(P);
    return app.exec();
}
```

**.pro file :**

```
QT += quick opengl
CONFIG += c++11
QT +=xml widgets

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target



unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/lib/ -lCGAL_Core

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/lib/ -lCGAL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/lib/ -lCGAL_Qt5

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER
LIBS+=-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER




unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/lib/ -lCGAL_ImageIO

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include



unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lQt5Xml

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lQt5OpenGL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lgmp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64



unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lboost_system

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
```

the source of example : https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_2draw_polyhedron_8cpp-example.html#a2

the problem is it shows black viewer , I don't know what's the problem 
[image]

I'm using qt-creator on Fedora OS
any help ,please?

Comment: It might be an opengl issue. Could you give some detail on your config and your graphic card driver ?

Comment: I tried the following opengl example:https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/simple/bitmap1.c and it works properly

Comment: @sloriot my graphics card :NVIDIA

Comment: I just realized that you have too many code in your example. Look at the minimal example [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_2draw_polyhedron_8cpp-example.html). The `draw()` function is already taking care of creating a Qt windows.